# Incorrext syntax near '=' error in SQL select query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Error Text : `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

What is the error in my Code?
How I Can Select It right 
this code to sure if this found or not

its All my Code  Plz Check It

its to check my value and update some it 
or insert

ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

```
  //Test For Insert Duplicate Row
                        int tst = 0;

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From Product Where ProdCode=@CodeVar And ProdName= @NameVar And BuyPrice=@PriceVar",conn);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CodeVar", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NameVar", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PriceVar", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        conn.Open();
                       SqlDataReader reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if(reader.Read())
                        {

                            if (Convert.ToInt16(reader[0]) > 0)
                            {
                                tst = 1;
                            }
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                        conn.Close();
                        // Test For Same Row But Anthor Code
                        cmd.CommandText = "Select Count(*) From Product Where ProdName=@PName And BuyPrice=@BPrice And Not ProdCode  = @Pcode And ProdCode BETWEEN @SCode And @SCode+2000";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PName",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value ;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BPrice", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[5].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pcode",SqlDbType.Int).Value =  Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SCode", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(label10.Text);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        conn.Open();
                      reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if(reader.Read())
                        {
                            if(Convert.ToInt16(reader[0])>0)
                            {
                                tst = 2;
                            }

                        }
                        reader.Close();
                        conn.Close();
                        cmd.CommandText = "Select Count(*) From Product Where ProdCode = @CodeVar1 ";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CodeVar1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        conn.Open();
                         reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {

                            if (Convert.ToInt16(reader[0]) > 0 && tst == 0)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("الأكواد باللون الأحمر خاصة احد الأصناف ..!");
                                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Style = redcell;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                        conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try to replace `ProdCode Not = @Pcode` with `ProdCode != @Pcode` or `ProdCode <> @Pcode` or `Not ProdCode = @Pcode`.

All should be valid in TSQL.

Comment: Or just stick the Not in front of the condition!

Comment: @JonEgerton - Added that possibility as well to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen Its Ok But This error show After edit As You Say
Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

Comment: @MohamedHmmam - Where in your code do you assign the reader? shouldn't the line `cmd.ExecuteReader();` really be `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: mmm  ok Iem edit my Question , And Write all my code Plz check it

Answer (score 2):

change

```
and ProdCode Not = @Pcode
```

to

```
and not ProdCode = @Pcode
```

Comment: Its Ok But This error show After edit As You Say Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

Comment: Well that is a totally different story.

Comment: Try executinng `con.Open()` **before** calling the `cmd` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `ProdCode Not = @Pcode` in your sql command with `ProdCode <> @Pcode`